# How to render a template from a new app on django-cookiecutter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, cookiecutter-django

I am having trouble with rendering a template from an app using Django-cookiecutter!

I am using Django-cookiecutter for my project and I am trying to create a new blog app in my project and I have kinda done everything following this tutorial: [Creating a blog part](https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/#share-your-knowledge-with-a-blog)

but I am stuck at the part where I am trying to render the template from my new app called algo_explained.

I tried following the user app inside the sample project but no luck.

[Here's the link to my project on github](https://github.com/Zamy97/Explain_Algorithms)

Here's what I have so far:

App views

explain_algorithms/explain_algorithms/algo_explained/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from explain_algorithms.algo_explained.models import Post, Comment
from explain_algorithms.algo_explained.forms import CommentForm

#blog_index will display a list of all your posts.

def blog_index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-created_on")
    context = {
        "posts" : posts,
    }
    return render(request, "blog_index.html", context)
```

app-specific URL

explain_algorithms/explain_algorithms/algo_explained/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "algo_explained"
urlpatterns = [
       path("blog", views.blog_index, name="blog_index"),
]
```

main project URL

explain_algorithms/config/urls.py

I do have admin and all other routes I just wanted to share what's important!

```
urlpatterns = [
path("users/", include("explain_algorithms.users.urls", namespace="users")),
path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),

# Your stuff: custom urls includes go here
path("algo_explained/", include("explain_algorithms.algo_explained.urls", namespace = 
"algo_explained")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and I do have the templates inside templates/algo_explained/blog_index.html

this is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN5xM.png)

I would appreciate any input!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok people after days of struggle I was able to solve this problem. I am going to share how I solved this which might help someone else.

I didn't have any problem configuring my new app in cookiecutter-Django. [Follow this link if you need to figure out how to configure it the right way](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/1876)

in addition, follow the User app to configure your urs in your main urls.py.

Changes that I needed to make was to be more explicit about where my template was inside the project. For example, this is what I had:

```
def blog_index(request):
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-created_on")
context = {
    "posts" : posts,
}
return render(request, "blog_index.html", context)`
```

and I changed it to:

```
def blog_index(request):
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-created_on")
context = {
    "posts" : posts,
}
**return render(request, "algo_explained/blog_index.html", context)**
```

[Look into these and see if you can solve your issue:](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20render%20a%20template%20in%20cookiecutter-django%20site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-he6TsonmAhWBrJ4KHTW1C8sQrQIoBDAAegQIAhAQ&biw=1280&bih=689)

Answer (score 0):

did you added your application to settings files ?

Comment: I think I was supposed to add that in base.py right? which I did inside Local_Apps.
here's a snap of it! 

`LOCAL_APPS = [
    "explain_algorithms.users.apps.UsersConfig",

    # Your stuff: custom apps go here
    "explain_algorithms.algo_explained.apps.AlgoExplainedConfig",
]`

Answer (score 0):

You should  just add appname to your setting files ..

Comment: as I have mentioned that I have done that already, would appreciate anything other input besides this!